# How to filter product by its Attribute in Django - Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm working on a Django Ecommerce project where product has several attributes like. size, color( A single product can have multiple attributes with different size and color).  No i'm trying to filter products using django_filters but unable to filter by its attributes.

**Product Model:**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    variations = (
        ('None', 'None'),
        ('Size', 'Size'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    store = models.ManyToManyField(Store)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True, max_length=500)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    tax = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    stock = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    variations = models.CharField(choices=variations, max_length=20)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    details = RichTextUploadingField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    discounted_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', default='product.png', null=True, 
    blank=True)
    image_one = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', null=True, blank=True)
    image_two = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', null=True, blank=True)
    image_three = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', null=True, blank=True)
    image_four = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', null=True, blank=True)
    image_five = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', null=True, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                 related_name='products')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=(('Active', 'Active'), ('Inactive', 
    'Inactive')))
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,
                              blank=True)  # This is used only for filtration
```

**Product attribute model**

```
class ProductAttribute(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, validators= 
    [MinValueValidator(1)])
    discounted_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    stock = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach would be to define the attributes in the "Product" model. However, if you insist on doing this, the code will be:

```
filtered_ProductAttributes=ProductAttribute.objects.filter(size="12")
products=[filtered_ProductAttribute.product for filtered_ProductAttribute in filtered_ProductAttributes]
```

As you can see the code seems very inefficient, therefore, as was suggested in the beginning put the attributes in the "Product" model and you will have:

```
products=Product.objects.filter(size="12")
```

Answer (score 1):

Refining your model will help you to filter.

With my experience following model approach will be more suitable:

```
 class Attributes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True,null=True)

class AttributeTerms(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank =True)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attributes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  

class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True, blank=True,)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True,null=True)
    

class ProductAttribute(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='attributes', default=None)
    attributes = models.ForeignKey(Attributes,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='attributes', default=None)
    values = models.ForeignKey(AttributeTerms, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='attributes', default=None)



class ProductVariant(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variant = models.ForeignKey(ProductAttribute,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True, default=None)
    stock = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    stock_threshold = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length= 250, default=None)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```